# How to insert record just before / after another record in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Currently, I have Laravel 9 project and I want to insert new record just above or below  another record in the database. But I am stuck at:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'....
```

Here is my code.

```
public function store(StoreCategoryRequest $request)
{
    $before_id = $request->before_id != 0 ? $request->before_id: null;
    $after_id = $request->after_id != 0 ? $request->after_id: null;

    $category = auth()->user()->categories()->create($request->validated());

    if (($before_id && !$after_id) || (!$before_id && $after_id)) 
    {
       Category::when($before_id && !$after_id,
            function ($query) use ($before_id) { return $query->where('id', '>=', $before_id); }
        )->when(!$before_id && $after_id,
            function ($query) use ($after_id) { return $query->where('id', '>', $after_id); }
        )->increment('id', 1);

        $category->update(['id' => $before_id ?? $after_id]);
    }

    return to_route('category.index')->with(feedback('New category inserted successfully.', 'success'));

}
```

**Is there any other way, please guide me.**

Comment: Since you had same id in your DB table it is throwing this error. Why do you need to change ID? You can add priority column to your table however you should reorder your table

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the answer. Here is the code:

```
Category::latest('id')->when($before_id && !$after_id,
    function ($query) use ($before_id) { return $query->where('id', '>=', $before_id); }
)->when(!$before_id && $after_id,
    function ($query) use ($after_id) { return $query->where('id', '>', $after_id); }
)->increment('id', 1);
  
Category::where('id', $category->id + 1)->update(['id' => $before_id ?? $after_id + 1]);
```